# What is \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE?

Tags: memory, hardware, hard-drive

What does \.\ mean>?
I have seen it mentioned in reference to mbr(master boot record) or when using it in rekall framework(live memory forensics framework).

Is it a way to make direct stream to the hard-disk?

I have tried searching it on google but all I found was bunch of people having hard time with their programs using this thing w/o explaining exactly what it is.

Answer (score 0):

You can access disk drive in "raw" mode, e.g. reading any block 0..N. If you open `C:` - it is logical volume.